# PhoneGap Fixed Orientation + ChildBrowser Non-Fixed Orientation (Android)

Tags: android, cordova

I'm creating a HTML/JS/CSS App using PhoneGap (1.4.1) for Android. Within the App I'm using the PhoneGap ChildBrowser plugin to display external content.

I'd like to keep the orientation of the App to Landscape while allowing the ChildBrowser to rotate to the orientation of the device.

I've tried applying different android:screenOrientation="" settings on each of the activities as below, but that doesn't seem to work.

```
<activity
    android:name="com.phonegap.DroidGap"
    android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape" >
    <intent-filter>
        ....
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name="com.phonegap.plugins.childBrowser.ChildBrowser"
    android:screenOrientation="sensor" >
    <intent-filter>
        ....
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Is this even possible?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: ever found a solution for this?