# Keep App orientation set to Portrait

Tags: android, orientation, cordova, phonegap-plugins, childbrowser

I am working on creating an Android App using Sencha Touch, PhoneGap and PhoneGap's `ChildBrowser` plugin.

I'd like to fix the orientation of the App itself to Portrait, but allow the `ChildBrowser` to rotate to the orientation of the device.

I tried detecting when the `ChildBrowser` activity is at `onResume`, but this didn't work. (maybe because it's extending a Plugin?)

Found a similar thread here, but no solution yet:
[PhoneGap Fixed Orientation + ChildBrowser Non-Fixed Orientation (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458670/phonegap-fixed-orientation-childbrowser-non-fixed-orientation-android)

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you've set your activity to have the attribute android:screenOrientation="portrait" and you are using the ChildBrowser.showWebPage command you are stuck as that opens a dialog inside the app, that is, it is still part of the app.

However, if you use ChildBrowser.openExternal then it opens the browser and landscape will be enabled again.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, doing so would open a new browser and there won't be any child browser. Is there a way, I can detect in code when the ChildBrowser launches and set the orientation to Sensor, otherwise portrait?

Comment: If I use childBrowser.openExternal(url, true);

it opens up the child browser in the phone gap's web view. However, it's still fixed in portrait.

Would really appreciate any help on this.

Comment: You'd have to build another activity that is not restricted to portrait only then have the HTML displayed in that activity.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like a great option. The only challenge I'm having is how to have the rest of the app run in the original main activity created by phone gap and just have the child browser run in this new second activity. Trying to do that using different options but haven't been successful so far.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I created another activity and fixed it.